# Eclipse - Obfuscate .java files and export them as .jar file automatically

Tags: eclipse, ant, jar, obfuscation, task

My dream when using the Eclipse IDE is to have my .java files obfuscated and exported to a .jar file automatically.

At the moment, I use two applications to repetitively perform my obfuscation and jar exportation, and it really is a pain!!!

If I'm correct, the only way to do this is to create my own Ant Task - if this is the case, may you guide me step by step on how to create this Ant Task?

Thank you gurus, I will soon be able to rest my hands for just that little bit longer!

Comment: Consider saving yourself (and your customers) the pain and hassle by dumping obfuscation.  It doesn't give you much protection in reality.  (And if your boss doesn't believe this, do an experiment to see how long it takes you to break whatever the obfuscation is protecting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/ant.html)  has ant tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Excelsior Jet has a [Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/excelsior-jet).